# Are there any short prose or poetry works in classical or modern Chinese designed specifically to teach the names of the 64 hexagrams?

Tags: vocabulary

For a while I have wanted to learn to match the character names of the 64 hexagrams to the hexagrams themselves.

Unfortunately, as for the names and hexagrams, none of them really stick in my memory.

Sure, the hexagrams all look alike at first.

But it's not so much that the characters themselves are hard to remember, or that the meanings are hard to remember. It's just that there are 64 of them.

What I usually do when absorbing a list-based piece of knowledge like this is to simply learn one half of the list in one big chunk, then go back and match the 'domain' to the 'range'.

With that in mind, I want to tackle the character names of the 64 hexagrams.

So, are there any short prose or poetry works in classical or modern Chinese designed specifically to teach the names of the 64 hexagrams?

I am thinking in particular of the 千字文, a work of poetry that was mainly designed to teach calligraphy, versions of the work being available in a variety of calligraphic styles. Didactic literature like this has played a useful part in my own study of Chinese.

The 百家姓 is another example.

Such a work, translated into English, might go something like,

"Sixty-three, the ox has already forded the stream,
But, sixty-four, the stag is still on the other side."

and would use the actual character names in the 'story', like 既济 for 'already forded.'

Answer (score 2):

I found this [link](http://www.360doc.com/content/12/0203/23/4891624_184009111.shtml). It's mainly focused on methods to quickly memorize the meaning and pattern of 64 hexagrams. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> 南宋理学家朱熹著有《周易本义·卦名次序歌》：
>
> ```
> 乾坤屯蒙需讼师，比小畜兮履泰否；
> 同人大有谦豫随，蛊临观兮噬嗑贲；
> 剥复无妄大畜颐，大过坎离三十备。
>
> 咸恒遁兮及大壮，晋与明夷家人睽；
> 蹇解损益夬姤萃，升困井革鼎震继；
> 艮渐归妹丰旅巽，兑涣节兮中孚至；
> 小过既济兼未济，是为下经三十四。
> ```

http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%AD%E5%8D%81%E5%9B%9B%E5%8D%A6